# What are the possible values of Z=X+Y

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If I have two independent probability mass function, where $P_{x}(0)=\frac{1}{2}$ ,  $P_{x}(2)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $P_{y}(1)=\frac{1}{6}$ ,  $P_{y}(2)=\frac{1}{3}$ ,  $P_{y}(3)=\frac{1}{2}$

I am asked to find sum of probability mass function $Z=X+Y$

Before diving into any kind of formula, what are the possible values of $Z$?

I think $0,1,2,3,4,5,6$ are values of $Z$, and have to find out $P_{z}(0), P_{z}(1),...,P_{z}(6)$

Do I understand it in right way?

Comment: How can $Z$ be $0$ or $6$? It's $X+Y$, not $XY$.

Comment: I get possible values $1,2,3,4,5$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the random variables, $X\in\{0,2\}$ and $Y\in\{1,2,3\}$, are *independently* distributed, then since $Z=X+Y$ we have:

$$\mathsf P_Z(z) = \sum\limits_{x}\mathsf P_X(x)\,\mathsf P_Y(z-x) \quad :x\in\{0,2\}\land (z-x)\in\{1,2,3\}$$

So you need to calculate the $P_Z(z)$ corresponding to each of $z\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

Comment: If X is {0,3}, then 1,2,3,4,5,6 are possible values of z?

Comment: @Nancy If that were the case, then yes.